# Mysql date range price

Tags: mysql, sql, database, date

I want to show price based on season date rage.

**Example:**

> Movies have different prices that are determined based on the date

season_1 = 2016-05-01 - 2016-08-31 price is 100$
season_2 = 2016-09-01 - 2017-04-31 price is 50$

I have two dates in table

**season_tbl:**

```
id    |   start_date   |  end_date   |  name
--------------------------------------------------
1     |  2016-05-01    | 2016-08-31  | season_1
2     |  2016-09-01    | 2017-04-30  | season_2
```

**movies_price_tbl:**

```
id    |   season_id    |  name            |  price | movie
------------------------------------------------------------
1     |  1             | Gladiator movie  | 100$   |  1
2     |  2             | Gladiator movie  | 50%    |  1
```

**What i expect:**

When user enter in search start `2016-06-01` end `2016-07-30` and select id of movie show price for that date. In this case show season_1 price `100$`.
If user enter start `2016-09-23` end `2017-01-21` show season_2 price

i try but not working:

```
WHERE m.movie_id = 1 AND s.start_date <= '2016-05-01' AND s.end_date >= '2016-07-20'
```

Comment: which is the data type for the columns start_date and end_date ?

Comment: Type of columns is first be `date` by i change it to `varchar`

Comment: Now  in db are varchar ? .. what result you get with your query  ? show all the query code you use ..

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this query will do:

```
SELECT movies_price_tbl.price FROM season_tbl 
  INNER JOIN movies_price_tbl ON season_tbl.id = movies_price_tbl.season_id 
    WHERE movies_price_tbl.movie = '1' 
    AND season_tbl.start_date <= '2016-05-01' 
    AND season_tbl.end_date >= '2016-07-20'
```

PS: You should get rid of the `name`-column in `movies_price_tbl`. There is no need for it, because there is a `movie_id`.

Comment: This example work but one dont work when i enter start date `2016-01-01` to end date `2016-02-01` return `null`. But all other in range work.

Comment: What else should be returned - you have no season defined between 2016-01-01 and 2016-02-01

Answer (score 0):

try this query

```
SELECT price FROM movies_price_tbl WHERE movie_id = 1 && season_id = (select id from season_tbl where start_date <= '2016-05-01' && end_date >= '2016-07-20')
```